# Can I use GCP Snapshot for data or database backup? can I trust the snapshot to restore my DB data?

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, snapshot

I am using the Google cloud platform and compute engine for my project, Installed MongoDB into the instance server, what is the best way to take my database back-up and restore

my options :

1. create a custom script to dump -> zip -> upload to cloud storage.
2. Use GCP snapshot to back-up data and restore while a new instance creating.

Let me know the best way of handling this.

Due to the non-reliable snapshot size got confused a bit.

**While schedule snapshot**

[image: Enable application consistent snapshot]

Comment: Is your MongoDB installation and setup is integrated with snapshoting? If not, no you can not trust the snapshots. The key is setting up **application consistent**. Start here: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/compute/implementing-application-consistent-data-protection-compute-engine-workloads

Comment: @JohnHanley, MongoDB installed at my instance, but what you mean by integrated with snapshoting?

Comment: @JohnHanley while taking snapshot manually I am able to see all apps MongoDB, Docker and PM2. all working fine at new instance created by snapshot

Comment: OK - but unless your apps are integrated with snapshotting, you only have crash-consistent snapshots. That is the same thing as pulling the power cord on a running server. I have seen countless snapshots that are corrupted. Verify with each vendor that their products are integrated - most are not. The few that are integrated require configuration on your part.

Comment: @JohnHanley, I am not enabled `Enable application consistent snapshot` checkbox while creating a snapshot schedule. Will it cause the problem later, app may crash some time?

Comment: If you want reliable snapshots, the simplest solution is to stop the instance. Create a snapshot and then restart the instance.

Comment: @JohnHanley I want to make it automated every day so I think `Enable application consistent snapshot` will do stop and take a snapshot?

Comment: If your applications are not integrated with snapshotting, that button will not help you. I provide you a link, please read it so that you understand how to setup snapshots that are reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use snapshot. Also consider below suggestion

**Use additional data disk attached to Compute Instance for Database.**
In case any failure detach the disk and attach to new vm instance.
Snapshot will help you in regional failure or when you need to restore backup in another region.Also snapshot size seems confusing to you because snapshots are incremental in nature.
ex. snapshot-1 taken at 2:00 AM contains 10GB data.
now you added 1 GB data to the disk at 2:30 AM and taken snapshot again at 3:00 AM.
snapshot-2 at 3:00 AM will only contains 1 GB of data ( not 11 GB).
but real magic is when you restore snapshot-2 , it will restore your complete 11GB of data as it contains reference to snapshot-1 with 10GB data.

Comment: I agreed that keeping a separate disk or instance for the database is good, at the snapshot we delete snapshot-1 then may crash the installation?

Answer (score 1):

Yes Snapshots are reliable. You can use snapshots to create point in time image for your disk. In your case, you can take data disk snapshots. To recover data from snapshot create a disk from snapshot and attach to existing vm.

To automate mounting this you can run the gcloud commands in a bash/python script. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/restore-snapshot#create-disk-from-snapshot

For taking regular snapshots you can setup snapshot schedule and how many times a day it should happen. To save costs you can keep retention too. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/scheduled-snapshots